# I want to reverse a string that has negative numbers by preserving it's format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I stuck at this simple scenario & not able to find smart solution to `Reverse a string` that has negative number.

```
Example 1:    str = "stack-1flow"  #Expected output- wolf-1kcats
```

#Note may input contain multiple negative like

```
Example 2:    str = "-1-2stack-1flow"  #Expected output - wolf-1kcats-2-1
```

I want to reverse this such that i must preserve negative number format. In my case it is pretty sure that no Hyphen's will appear in input string except from `Negative numbers`.

**Expected output**

```
wolf-1kcats
```

1. I've tried normal sort it wont yeild required resulsts`(wolf1-kcats` -
   wrong)

   ```
   'stack-1flow'[::-1] #outputs wolf1-kcats -wrong
   ```
2. Tried appending to list & then reversed the list yeild
   same(`wolf1-kcats` - wrong)

   ```
   list('stack-1flow') # ['s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', '-', '1', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w'] #Reversing fails as you can see `-1` not preserved
   ```
3. Tried `eval` same results.

> Note: I prefer Regex will be my last option..Before that I want to
> take help of 1.9M community people suggests me is there is any way to
> solve without `Regex`.

Comment: You say you've tried things.  Please post the code for some of the things you've tried, or at least for the thing you've tried that got you the closest.  You'll be better served by allowing us to help you to fix your code rather than having someone write the entire solution for you.

Comment: Yeah adding them ...Just a sec

Comment: And what about positive numbers? What should be the result of `stack123flow`? Or `stack-123flow` ?

Comment: No @AndrejKesely `wolf321kcats` ...As no negative everything will be same

Comment: `wolf-1kcats` is reverse of ` stack-1flow` ...I just want ro reverse string should ignore negative numbers

Comment: what about multiple digits? "stack-123flow", should it be "wolf-123kcats"?

Comment: Yes true @HaiVu

Comment: What about "abc-123def-456ghi"? Should it be "ihg-456fed-123cba"?

Comment: Exactly...Once negative number appears until it ends it will be same num @HaiVu

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `re`,

```
import re
re.search(r'-\d', s).group().join(map(lambda x:x[::-1], re.split(r'-\d', s)[::-1]))

# 'wolf-1kcats'
```

Split the string with `re.split` (using a regex) and revere the list of elements and join the values with the same regex.

**EDIT**

For the updated requirements you can do this,

```
''.join(i if i.lstrip('-').isdigit() else i[::-1] for i in re.split(r"(-?\d+)", s)[::-1])
# 'wolf-1kcats-2-1'
```

Comment: Trying this asap

Comment: Ahh your case fails with consiquetive numbers @Rahul liek `s = "-1-2stack-1flow"` which giving me `wolf-1kcats-1-1`

Comment: @Bhargav You need to alter the regex expression according to that. The current approach will explicitly work in the mentioned case in the question. Please elaborate on the question according to this with the expected answer.

Comment: Sorry Rahul..Just updated

Comment: @Bhargav Updated my answer as well.

Comment: I was checking @Rahul...Trying to execute all possible combinations...Logic is impresive!!..Passed more than a quatar million test cases

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, without `re`:

```py
s = "-1-2-87a"

to_sort = []
i, flag = 0, 0
for ch in s:
    if ch == "-":
        flag = 1
        i += 1
    elif flag and not ch.isdigit():
        flag = 0
        i += 1
    to_sort.append(-i)
    i += not flag

print("".join(s[idx] for _, idx in sorted(zip(to_sort, range(len(s))))))
```

Prints:

```
a-87-2-1
```

Comment: Ahh thank you @kesely I will test once I tested Rahul logic

Comment: Logic is eligant & clean!!...This fail when I take `s = "-1-2-87a"` it is rerurning `a-78-2-1` ...It should return `a-87-2-1`

Comment: @Bhargav Should be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is my plan:

1. First reverse the whole string: "stack-1flow" -> "wolf1-kcats"
2. Use the `re.sub` to reverse the numbers: "1-" -> "-1", "321-" -> "-123"

Code:

```py
import re

def reverse_negative_number(match: re.Match):
    result = "".join(reversed(match[0]))
    return result

def reverse_string_with_negative_numbers(input_string):
    print(f"Input:     {input_string}")
    out1 = "".join(reversed(input_string))
    print(f"Reversed1: {out1}")
    
    out2 = re.sub(r"\d+-", reverse_negative_number, out1)
    print(f"Reversed2: {out2}")
    return out2

    
input_strings = [
    "stack-1flow",
    "abc-123def-456ghi",
]

for input_string in input_strings:
    result = reverse_string_with_negative_numbers(input_string)
    print(result)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Input:     stack-1flow
Reversed1: wolf1-kcats
Reversed2: wolf-1kcats
wolf-1kcats

Input:     abc-123def-456ghi
Reversed1: ihg654-fed321-cba
Reversed2: ihg-456fed-123cba
ihg-456fed-123cba
```

#### Notes

- A little known fact. The `re.sub` function:

  ```
    re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
  ```

  can take in a function in place of the replacement, `repl`. This function must accept a `re.Match` object and return a string.
- That function in this case is `reverse_negative_number`, which takes in something like "321-" and reverse it.
- These functions look long, but because they have a bunch of `print()` for demo/debug purpose. Once you are happy with the result, you can delete them.